# Show last record in db table Rails .last method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have 2 tables with a relation between them:

Users table: user_id,

Blogs table: user_id, blog_content,

Im working with a view that should show a users latest blog entry.. When I use

<%= @users.blogs.last %>

I get "#"

Can someone assist as to why its showing "#" and how to actually show the the last blog entry made by a @user?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out, I needed to define what part of the hash I needed to show

<%= @users.blogs.last[:blog_content] %>

Comment: +1 for answering your own question correctly and beating me to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought you want to do:

```
<%= @users.blogs.last.blog_content %>
```

What you've done will try and display the Blog object itself with the `to_s` method, which returns something that looks like the following:

```
#<Blog:0x?????????>
```

Which on screen will just look like a hash.